# Increase size in convert

Tags: java

I found this example of a program which converts input and prints it based on the value. But I noticed that if I add bigger value I get error

```
integer number too large: 9394343298
```

Is there any way to fix this?

```
String readableFileSize = readableFileSize(939343298);

System.out.println("Result " + readableFileSize);

public static String readableFileSize(long size)
{
    if (size <= 0)
        return "0";
    final String[] units = new String[] {"B", "kB", "MB", "GB", "TB"};
    int digitGroups = (int) (Math.log10(size) / Math.log10(1024));
    return new DecimalFormat("#,##0.#").format(size / Math.pow(1024, digitGroups)) + " " + units[digitGroups];
}
```

Comment: Works for me: http://ideone.com/NEbz6s

Comment: @Zelldon you did not tried to change `939343298` to `9394343298`.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `L` in the end of number to mark it as long value:

`String readableFileSize = readableFileSize(9394343298L);`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if you use a constant value the default is integer but integer max size is 2147483647 which is < 9394343298. So
the compilation error appears:

```
Main.java:15: error: integer number too large: 9394343298
        String readableFileSize = readableFileSize(9394343298);
```

So either you use the 'L' after the constant value to mark the value as a long or you use a long variable which will be given into the function.

Like so:

```
long value = 9394343298L;
String readableFileSize = readableFileSize(value);
```

See the Example:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Ideone
{

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String readableFileSize = readableFileSize(9394343298L);
        System.out.println("Result " + readableFileSize);
    }



    public static String readableFileSize(long size)
    {
            if (size <= 0)
                return "0";
            final String[] units = new String[]
            {
                "B", "kB", "MB", "GB", "TB"
            };
            int digitGroups = (int) (Math.log10(size) / Math.log10(1024));
            return new DecimalFormat("#,##0.#").format(size / Math.pow(1024, digitGroups)) + " " + units[digitGroups];
    }
}
```

Working Example:

http://ideone.com/QA1sCL

Comment: Unfortunately I can't add L at the end. Is there any way to refactor the code to accept bigger values?

Comment: I get the value from network client. I can't make this change - it's a 3p library.

Comment: Thats will be a problem - then you are bound to the int value and his MAX_VALUE because if he gives you a int value this value can't be larger than the MAX_VALUE of int.

Comment: Is there any possible way to fix this?

Comment: Only if you are able to change the type of the given value - to string, byte array or long.